# Sum two columns from two tables without cartesian

Tags: mysql, join, cartesian

I searched for a while but nothing I find fixes my problem...

I have two tables: earnings, expenses

I have the columns:

- earnings.amount
- earnings.date
- expenses.amount
- expenses.date

I want to sum the amount of all my earnings and show them by year and month, so I do this and it works perfectly...

```
SELECT
     DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y%m') AS 'date',
     SUM(amount) as 'total_earnings'
FROM earnings
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y%m')
```

The output is similar to this...

```
date,total_earnings
201901,5000
201902,5500
201903,6200
etc.
```

I do the same for the expenses table and all is well.

**My problem:**
When I try to write a query that shows me total earnings and total expenses grouped by year and month I get a cartesian result that shows huuuge numbers.

This is an example query that shows a cartesian result:

```
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(ea.date, '%Y%m') AS date,
    SUM(ea.amount) AS 'total_earnings',
    SUM(ex.amount) AS 'total_expenses',
FROM earnings ea
    INNER JOIN expenses ex
        ON DATE_FORMAT(ea.date, '%Y%m') = DATE_FORMAT(ex.date, '%Y%m')
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(ex.date, '%Y%m')
```

How can I show the total amount of monthly earnings and monthly expenses in a single query?

**Desired output:**

```
date,total_earnings,total_expenses
201901,5000,1000
201902,5500,1100
201903,6200,1250
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should do the join AFTER the sum has been made, ie, two subqueries to get date, sum() and then join them using the date field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to aggregate first, then `JOIN`

```
SELECT ea.date, total_earnings, total_expenses
FROM (
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y%m') AS date
        , SUM(amount) AS total_earnings
    FROM earnings 
    GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y%m')
) ea
JOIN (
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y%m') AS date
        , SUM(amount) AS total_expenses
    FROM expenses
    GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y%m')
) ex ON ex.date = ea.date
```

Comment: Thanks, Eric. I'm trying to translate this logic to my real table and column names... your code has an additional comma after each 'AS date'.

Comment: @Haddock-san Updated.

Comment: This way the logic that worked, thanks! I had to tweak it a lot for it to fit exactly into what I needed (the example in the question was over-simplified). Thanks, Eric!

Comment: What about when there's only earnings or expense in one month, the `join`  will not include that in the results.

Comment: @Kerkouch Then he can turn it into `LEFT/RIGHT/FULL JOIN` as required.

Comment: Left join & right join won't work, also I guess MySQL does not support FULL JOIN.

Comment: @Kerkouch Why won't `LEFT/RIGHT JOIN` not work? There are many reference how to do `FULL JOIN` in `MySQL`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you don't need a join ..

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t
(expense_amount int,expense_date date, earnings_amount int, earnings_date date);

insert into t values
(10,'2020-01-01',null,null),
(10,'2020-01-01',null,null),
(10,'2020-02-01',null,null),
(null,null,10,'2020-01-01'),
(10,'2020-03-01',10,'2020-03-01');


select coalesce(expense_date,earnings_date) date,
         sum(case when expense_amount is not null then expense_amount else 0 end) expense,
         sum(case when earnings_amount is not null then earnings_amount else 0 end) earnings
from t
group by coalesce(expense_date,earnings_date);

+------------+---------+----------+
| date       | expense | earnings |
+------------+---------+----------+
| 2020-01-01 |      20 |       10 |
| 2020-02-01 |      10 |        0 |
| 2020-03-01 |      10 |       10 |
+------------+---------+----------+
3 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

If your data model is different in that 1 row can contain expense and earnings with different dates then this won't work for you and you should generate the totals separately and join them.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that using a subquery:

```
SELECT `date`, SUM(earnings) AS total_earnings, SUM(expenses) AS total_expenses
FROM (
         SELECT DATE_FORMAT(earnings.date, '%Y%m') AS `date`, `amount` AS earnings, 0 AS expenses
         FROM earnings
         UNION
         SELECT DATE_FORMAT(expenses.date, '%Y%m') AS `date`, 0 AS earnings, `amount` AS expenses
         FROM expenses
     ) expenses_earnings
GROUP BY `date`
```

#### Edit:

Using `YEAR(date)` and `MONTH(date)` instead of `DATE_FORMAT`, that will allow you to calculate the total of each year and the grand total using rollup.

```
SELECT `year`, `month`, SUM(earnings) AS total_earnings, SUM(expenses) AS total_expenses
FROM (
         SELECT YEAR(earnings.date) AS `year`, MONTH(earnings.date) AS `month`, `amount` AS earnings, 0 AS expenses
         FROM earnings
         UNION
         SELECT YEAR(expenses.date) AS `year`, MONTH(expenses.date) AS `month`, 0 AS earnings, `amount` AS expenses
         FROM expenses
     ) expenses_earnings
GROUP BY `year`, `month`
```